# Process is hanging all the time

Tags: docker, shell

Here is my script:

```
mogo()  
{  
sshpass -p 'abc123' ssh -tt -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no admin@192.168.10.145 <<'SSH_EOF'  
sudo docker exec -it $(sudo docker ps --filter name=mongo --format "{{.Names}}") bash -c "mongodump -d saas -u abc -p abc123 -o md1/"  
logout  
SSH_EOF  

touch /home/admin/11jul20  
}
```

I am calling above script using cronjob for taking backup.

Issue: the process created by the above script hangs forever and
the touch command after logout is not executed.

Manual workaround: If I terminate the process manually with the kill command. The touch command is running and the file 11jul20 got created.

If I remove single quotes `''` to `'SSH_EOF'` sudo docker command not taking backup, but the touch command is running.

Kindly help me to understand what is wrong.

Comment: Where is the closing `SSH_EOF`?

Comment: @KamilCuk sorry typo error

Comment: `-it` option to `docker exec` is probably the problem if you are calling this unattended. Just try to remove it and see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: @Zeitounator Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I tried and its working.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your issue is related to the password request of `sudo` going to the pseudo terminal specified by your `ssh -tt` (which is not a real terminal).
I avoid sshpass and never install it (it's a security risk) so I can't test your script.
However, the following will work.

1. Make your ssh login account part of the `docker` group

```
sudo usermod -a -G admin docker
```

As an aside, instead of using an 'admin' account, it would be a lot more secure to create a special login account (maintenance) on your linux box that can perform only the admin tasks needed.

2. User the following script

```
mogo()  
{  
ssh -T -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no admin@192.168.10.145 <<SSH_EOF
docker exec -it \$(docker ps --filter name=mongo --format "{{.Names}}") bash -c "mongodump -d saas -u $MGO_USER -p $MGO_PWD -o md1/"  
logout  
SSH_EOF  

touch /home/admin/11jul20  
}
```

Note that there is no need for pseudo terminal so we disable it (`-T`). I'd also look at not disabling `StrictHostKeyChecking`.


3. Set your env.
Keep your passwords and other secrets as environment variables ([12 factors](https://12factor.net/config)), never in your scripts. That's a minimum.
For instance, the following will be injected in your heredoc script.
**IMPORTANT** make sure you don't use single quotes around `SSH_EOF`, otherwise the var replacement isn't performed.

```
export MGO_USER=abc
export MGO_PWD=abc123
```

Docker has also a [secrets](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/) store and other open source [vaults](https://www.vaultproject.io) are available, but with more complexity.

4. Call your backup script

```
mgo
```

Comment: Bernard Thanks for your answer, I need time to understand your inputs.